# Removing EOL from a C++ string but preserving the '\0'

Tags: c++, string

This is probably a dumb question but if I have a C++ string as follows,

```
str = "the cat is black\n"
```

If I remove the last character, namely '\n', does this leave me with a null terminated string?  Does the statement below work in creating a null terminated char * from the original string str?

```
char *c = str.erase(str.size()-1).c_str();
```

Comment: You remove the last character by moving a `'\0'` there, because that `'\0'` terminates the string.

Comment: @Rhymoid: That's a bit of a simplification... the string will also typically have a length field which is updated, and you can have an `\0` in the middle of your string, if you want.

Comment: For C `'\n'` removal, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359

Comment: Suggest removing C from "c++ c string" tags.

Comment: `std::string::erase` keeps the string internals all sorted correctly (as do all member functions, etc.), so `.c_str()` will behave as with any `std::string` object (i.e. null terminated).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, std::string::c_str() will always return a null-terminated string.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

Comment: Thanks!!  I'm understanding that as long as it's a c.str() then the '\0' termination is automatic,

Answer (score 0):

If it is a C string as for example

```
char str[] = "the cat is black\n";
```

you can do this like

```
str[strcspn( str, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

If it is an object of type `std::string` as for example

```
std::string str( "the cat is black\n" );
```

you can write

```
if ( str.back() == '\n' ) str.erase( str.size() - 1 );
```

or

```
if ( !str.empty() && str.back() == '\n' ) str.erase( str.size() - 1 );
```

This statement

```
const char *c = str.erase( str.size() - 1 ).c_str();
^^^^^
```

is also valid provided that the string contains the new line character or empty.